# when i enter the username and password CORRECTLY it brings me over to the index.php?error=wrongpwd, wehn it should be saying ?login=success

Tags: php, mysql, sql, password-hash

```
<?php
// this is obviously just an includes file called login.inc.php.
if (isset($_POST['login-submit'])) {

    require 'dbh.inc.php';

    $mailuid = $_POST['mailuid']; //I also checked if all the database names are the same as here
    $password = $_POST['pwd'];

    if (empty($mailuid) || empty($password)) {
        header("Location: ../index.php?error=emptyfields");
        exit();
    }
    else {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE uidUsers=? OR emailUsers=?;";//selecting
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
            header("Location:../index.php?error=sqlerror");
        exit();
        }
        else {

            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $mailuid, $mailuid);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
            if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $pwdCheck == password_verify($password, $row['pwdUsers']);
                if ($pwdCheck == false) {
                    header("Location:../index.php?error=wrongpwd");
                    exit();
                }
                else if ($pwdCheck == true) {
                    session_start();
                    $_SESSION['userId'] = $row['idUsers'];
                    $_SESSION['userUid'] = $row['uidUsers'];

                    header("Location:../index.php?login=success");
                    exit();
                }
                else {
                    header("Location:../index.php?error=wrongpwd");
                    exit();
                }
            }
            else {
                header("Location:../index.php?error=nouser");
                exit();
            }

        }
    }

}
else {
    header("Location: ../index.php");//just the message of either I am logged in or out
    exit();
}
```

It keeps saying wrongpwd even though it is right, in which case it should be showing me the message that login=success.
I also checked all the names i made in the database its all correct.
Also I'm a beginner this is only like my first year of learning programming, so it would be greatly appreciated if you guys could help me :)

Comment: This: `$pwdCheck == password_verify($password, $row['pwdUsers']);` can **only be returning false**.  Therefore, your `$password` and `$row[...]` do not match.

Answer (score -2):

[EDIT: I assumed in my answer you are comparing unhashed password, which is not clear at the moment.]

Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow!

You should check the function password_verify().

Your code works on the assumption that password_verify compares two strings. It does something else.

If you just want to compare 2 strings do it like this:

```
$pwdCheck == ($password === $row['pwdUsers']);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Comment: How did you come to this conclusion?

Comment: @Dharman: because he is a self proclaimed newbie, so I don't think it is a stretch to expect he is comparing passwords without hashing algorithm. (But maybe he is, I can indeed not be sure.)

Comment: If he is using verify function I think it's safe to assume he hashed it first.

Comment: I completely copied the code from a mmtuts video from 5yrs ago, has something changed or ....?

Comment: read the documentation of password_verify() the second argument should be a hash.

Comment: i did hash my password in the signup includes file                                             
  else {
        $hashedPwd = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $username, $email, $hashedPwd);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=success");
        exit();
        }
        }